# Laravel query para traer todos los comentarios de un post

Tags: php, laravel, json, poo

Estoy haciendo una api con laravel (a modo de aprendizaje), tengo en mi base de datos dos tablas una es `Avisos` y otra llamada `Valoraciones`, avisos contiene como su nombre lo dice avisos que pueden ser comentados, osea tener varios comentarios (valoraciones = comentarios) **La relacion de las tablas es 1(aviso) a muchos(comentarios)**

Lo que quiero es traer todos los comentarios que contiene una publicación de la siguiente manera:

```
Aviso{//esto es a modo de ejemplo
   idAviso:1,
   tituloAviso:"Ejemplo de titulo",
   descripcionAviso:"Ejemplo de descrpoicion",
   valoraciones:[
      {
        idValoracion:1,
        DespcripcionValoracion:"ejemplo de descripcion"
      },
      {
        idValoracion:2,
        DespcripcionValoracion:"ejemplo de descripcion2sada"
      }
   ]
}
```

Lo que he intentado hasta el momento es usar un `left join` pero no son los resultados esperados, como muestro a continuacion

```
[
   {
    "id": 60,
    "titulo": "Ejemplo1",
    "descripcion": "Ejemplo1",
    "imagen": "ErrorIngresoHosp.jpg",
    "fecha": "2022-06-02 18:59:05",
    "name": "David Garcia",
    "comentario": "Ejemplo de comentario.."
   },
   {
    "id": 60,
    "titulo": "Ejemplo1",
    "descripcion": "Ejemplo1",
    "imagen": "ErrorIngresoHosp.jpg",
    "fecha": "2022-06-02 18:59:05",
    "name": "David Garcia",
    "comentario": "exste es otro ejemplo de comentario"
   },
   {
    "id": 61,
    "titulo": "Ejemplo2",
    "descripcion": "Ejemplo2",
    "imagen": "ErrorIngresoHosp.jpg",
    "fecha": "2022-06-02 18:59:13",
    "name": "David Garcia",
    "comentario": null
   },
   {
    "id": 62,
    "titulo": "Ejemplo3",
    "descripcion": "Ejemplo3",
    "imagen": "Hacker-Anonymous-wants-you.png",
    "fecha": "2022-06-03 15:21:56",
    "name": "David Garcia",
    "comentario": null
   }
 ]
```

Como se puede observar cada publicación que tiene comentario la trae dos veces **por eso la publicación con id 60 esta dos veces** porque ha sido comentada dos veces, actualmente my query esta de esta forma:

```
public function index()
{
    //Listamos todos los avisos
    $avisos = new Avisos();
    $avisos =  Avisos::select(
        'Avisos.id',
        'Avisos.titulo',
        'Avisos.descripcion',
        'Avisos.imagen',
        'Avisos.created_at as fecha',
        'users.name',
        'valoraciones.comentario'
        )->join('categorias','categorias.id', '=','avisos.idCategoria')
        ->join('estados','estados.id', '=','avisos.idEstado')
        ->join('users','users.id', '=','avisos.idUsuario')
        ->leftjoin('valoraciones','valoraciones.idAviso', '=','avisos.id')
        ->get(); 
    return response()->json([ 
        "Avisos" => $avisos
    ], Response::HTTP_OK);
}
```

Si la comunidad de desarrolladores me puede ayudar lo agradecería, o guiarme como podria ser mejor, en caso de que necesite usar subconsultas

Imagen de base de datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar el código de tu modelo `Avisos`? Si ya tienes la relación definida ahí puedes usarla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar Eloquent para facilitar el listado de las relaciones.

En tu modelo de avisos (app/Models/Aviso.php si estás usando php >= 8.0) creas la relación con valoraciones:

```
public function valoraciones()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Valoraciones::class, 'idAviso');
}
```

Al momento de consultar los avisos lo pueden hacer con:

```
$avisos = Avisos::with('valoraciones')->get();
```

La esto debería añadir a cada aviso sus valoraciones.

Comment: Excelente, gracias por tu respuesta!